# Property of the Dirac delta

Tags: distribution-theory, dirac-delta

I'm trying to see if the following identity is true:
$$ \mathrm{exp} \left(a x_0 \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_0}\right)\delta(x-x_0) = \delta\left(x-\mathrm{e}^a x_0\right)$$
where $a$ is a constant. If it is true, how should I prove it? I tried using this well known property:
$$\delta(g(x))=\sum_j \frac{\delta(x-x_j)}{|g'(x_j)|},$$
but it led to nowhere (or maybe I just got very confused with notation), and I don't see any other useful properties of the delta for this. Help appreciated!

Comment: $\exp(axD)f(x) = f(e^a x)$, so in your case the result trivially follows symbolically. Formalizing that depends on you define a differential operator to act on distributions, but you could take a weak limit of analytic things in the appropriate sense. Proving that the differential operator acts this way can be found by messing around with Taylor Series, a technique used to prove Lie's theorem on advective flows.

Comment: I see. Thank you!

Comment: I don't understand the question or the comment. What is $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_0}$ in the question exponential and $D$ in the comment exponential? In the question $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_0}$ seems to imply a deriviative, but nothing is specified to the right of $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_0}$ which would seem to imply its the derivative of $1$ which is zero and since $exp(0)=1$ this would imply the left-hand side simplifies to $\delta(x-x_0)$.

Comment: Working backwards from the right-hand side the well known property simply leads to $\delta\left(x-\mathrm{e}^a x_0\right)=\delta\left(x-\mathrm{e}^a x_0\right)$ which implies there is no simplification of the right-hand side.

Comment: This came up in my physics research, that's probably why the notation is confusing. The partial derivative is acting like an operator, so you can't simplify it that easily. If you take the Taylor series of the exponential, you will see that the real meaning is a sum of $n$ derivatives of the delta function. I hope this makes my question clearer.

Comment: @StevenClark It's a differential operator. Wikipedia gives some basic examples on the page on [Shift operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_operator). It's an operator defined implicitly by how it should act if one expands it as a Taylor Series. Comments are not the place to ask about this though, and you should create your own post if you are confused.